# Do two halves make a whole?

Tags: dna

[image]Jack has a half brother. Jill has that same half brother. Jack and Jill are not related.
Jack and Jill have a child.

The brother becomes the half uncle to the child on his brothers side and on his sisters side.
Does the brother then become a whole uncle?
Would having over a 1600 cm connection to the uncle make sense in this scenario?

Comment: This is quite confusing, could you include a diagram? How can Jack and Jill have the same brother but not be brother and sister themselves? Is the brother a half brother/sister to Jack and Jill?

Comment: I updated the verbage to show that they are in fact half siblings and provided a diagram. Hopefully, you can make sense of this as yes you are correct it is very confusing.

Comment: Sounds like one of those puzzles where Jack was wearing a red hat, and Jill was wearing tennis shoes, which one had on blue jeans?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you defined "whole uncle" to mean having the same expected amount of DNA inherited
in common from the grandparents, then yes, "Brother" in your diagram becomes a "whole" uncle.
By grandparents I mean, Father A, Mom A, Mom B and Father C in your diagram.
However, given the raw DNA data of this "whole uncle" and the (grand)daughter, one
could detect a difference from a full-siblings of a parent.

There are a number of precise details about how those cM numbers are calculated
where I'm not sure how big of a difference this would make.

This situation can be quantified in terms of amount of DNA inherited
in common from the grandparents. It will be helpful to remember that all of us
are a pairing of maternal and paternal DNA (in roughly equal parts).

Here are the %'s of DNA expected to be inherited in common from the
grandparents (by these decedents of those grandparents).

- Jack <-> Jill: 0%
- "Brother" <-> Jack: 25%
- "Brother" <-> Jill: 25%
- "Daughter" <-> Jack: 50%
- "Daughter" <-> Jill: 50%
- "Brother" <-> "Daughter": 25%
- Full-sibling of parent <-> "Daughter": 25%

However the 25% of "Brother" <-> "Daughter" is spread across both
maternal and paternal DNA of "Daughter". In contrast, a full-sibling of say Jack
would only have DNA in common in the paternal DNA of "Daughter" and non of the
maternal DNA of "Daughter". This subtle difference I doubt will show up in the cM
measurement. But with the raw DNA data, there are other measurements that could
detect this difference.

Comment: Castedo, How would I go about having that other measurement done?

Comment: @Taber-Brown, please mark my answer in StackExchange as the answer if you 
consider it an answer, thank you.

I doubt there is any easy way to get a single number summarizing
this other measurement. However you likely can visually see the effect of this
unusual uncle relationship. You can visually see the effect through a technique
many genetic genealogists call 'chromosome mapping' or 'chromosome painting'.

I have a much longer answer with URLs and more details, but StackExchange does
not allow long comments and wants you to create a new StackExhange question for
your 2nd question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a really simple way to think about this.

The double half uncle is a half brother of Jack, sharing one of Jack's parents.

The double half uncle is a half brother of Jill, sharing one of Jill's parents.

To the child, the double half uncle shares two grandparents, just like a real uncle does, except not both from one parent.

DNA wise, the child will on average share half the DNA with a half uncle than with a full uncle. Yes, you double this for a double half uncle and the two halves are effectively the equivalent of a whole.

Your diagram might be have been clearer if you combined the two Father A's and two Mother B's in a way that indicates they are the same people. Something like this:

[image]

where the Double half brother of Jack and Jill is also the Double half uncle of their child.